# Multiplying My Array Values

Tags: c#, arrays

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double[] values = new double[5];
        int i;
        double multValue;

        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter value for number " + (i+1) + ": ");
            values[i] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        Console.Write("Enter a value to multiply by: ");
        multValue = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        values[1] = values[1] * multValue;
        values[2] = values[2] * multValue;
        values[3] = values[3] * multValue;
        values[4] = values[4] * multValue;
        values[5] = values[5] * multValue;

        Console.WriteLine("The new value for values[1] is: " + values[1]);
        Console.WriteLine("The new value for values[2] is: " + values[2]);
        Console.WriteLine("The new value for values[3] is: " + values[3]);
        Console.WriteLine("The new value for values[4] is: " + values[4]);
        Console.WriteLine("The new value for values[5] is: " + values[5]);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Was wondering what exactly I have to do in order to multiply each value of my array. So, for instance, if the user inputs each value as 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 and then multiplies it by 2 then I want the values of each element to be changed to 20, 40, 60, 80, 100 and then displayed. I was thinking that processing this with loops would be easier, but I'm lost as how to do it.
Thanks!

Comment: You collect the initial values as a loop. What are you struggling with to do the multiplication inside a similar loop?

Comment: Whenever I run the code, an "IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled" message comes up. I'm not sure why at all. :\

Comment: Because C# arrays use zero-based indexing i.e. the first element is 0. The line values[5] = values[5] * multValue is bad. The max index value is always length-1 => 4

Comment: Arrays and loops go together like bread and butter. When you find yourself copying-and-pasting a line of code to just change an array index, you should use a loop instead. If you tried this and got an error message, you should show us what you tried and the **exact** error message so that we can help.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the LINQ [Select()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx) extension method:

```
values = values.Select(d => d * multValue).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

One loop for multiplying and another for printing.

**Use the following:**

```
// One loop to multiply them
for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
    values[i] *= multValue;
}

// One loop to print them
for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The new value for values[{0}] is: {1}", i, values[i]);
}
```

**Instead of:**

```
values[1] = values[1] * multValue;
values[2] = values[2] * multValue;
values[3] = values[3] * multValue;
values[4] = values[4] * multValue;
values[5] = values[5] * multValue;

Console.WriteLine("The new value for values[1] is: " + values[1]);
Console.WriteLine("The new value for values[2] is: " + values[2]);
Console.WriteLine("The new value for values[3] is: " + values[3]);
Console.WriteLine("The new value for values[4] is: " + values[4]);
Console.WriteLine("The new value for values[5] is: " + values[5]);
```

Answer (score 2):

To multiply all the items in the array just use another loop

```
for (i = 0; i < values.Length ; i++)
{
    values[i] *= multValue; // short for values[i] = values[i] * multValue
}
```

> Whenever I run the code, an "IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled"
>   message comes up

The error `IndexOutOfRangeException` is because `Array` indexes are fro 0 to array size - 1. You are trying to access index of `values` size in `values[5] = values[5] * multValue;`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I hope the following helps; using a loop should be something like this:

```
for(int i= 0; i<values.length; i++){
     values[i] = values[i] * multValue;
}
```